# Problems with SQL syntax

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax

```
    CREATE VIEW hd3_b 
AS 
  SELECT CASE 
           WHEN hd.country_visited = 'USA' THEN 'AMERICA' 
           WHEN hd.country_visited = 'India' THEN 'ASIA' 
           WHEN hd.country_visited = 'CHINA' THEN 'ASIA' 
           WHEN hd.country_visited = 'SPAIN' THEN 'EUROPE' 
           ELSE hd.country_visited 
         END AS hd.COUNTRY_VISITED 
  FROM   holiday_details hd 
  UNION 
  SELECT hd.holiday_desc, 
         holiday_code 
  FROM   holiday_details hd
```

This is the code that i currently have, i keep getting either FROM missing errors, or MISSING KEYWORD errors.

Can anyone see any blinding errors in my syntax?

Comment: It would help if you could post the exact error message you are getting.

Comment: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected,

Comment: Removing one of the columns from the second select did not fix the problems either

Answer (score 4):

You have a few errors.  You appear to be selecting a different number of columns with both `SELECT` statements. when you are using a `UNION` the column numbers must be equal:

```
CREATE VIEW hd3_b 
AS 
  SELECT CASE 
           WHEN hd.country_visited = 'USA' THEN 'AMERICA' 
           WHEN hd.country_visited = 'India' THEN 'ASIA' 
           WHEN hd.country_visited = 'CHINA' THEN 'ASIA' 
           WHEN hd.country_visited = 'SPAIN' THEN 'EUROPE' 
           ELSE hd.country_visited 
         END AS COUNTRY_VISITED,  -- remove the hd alias
         Null as PlaceholderColumn  
  FROM   holiday_details hd 
  UNION 
  SELECT hd.holiday_desc, 
         holiday_code 
  FROM   holiday_details hd
```

You also have a table alias on the column name in the first select.

If you only want to return one column, then you will want to use:

```
CREATE VIEW hd3_b 
AS 
  SELECT CASE 
           WHEN hd.country_visited = 'USA' THEN 'AMERICA' 
           WHEN hd.country_visited = 'India' THEN 'ASIA' 
           WHEN hd.country_visited = 'CHINA' THEN 'ASIA' 
           WHEN hd.country_visited = 'SPAIN' THEN 'EUROPE' 
           ELSE hd.country_visited 
         END AS COUNTRY_VISITED  -- remove the hd alias
  FROM   holiday_details hd 
  UNION 
  SELECT hd.holiday_desc
  FROM   holiday_details hd
```

Besides the queries having the same number of columns in each `SELECT` you are also required to have the same data types for each column.  If they are not the same, then you will need to perform a `CAST` of any of the columns to get the data type the same.

Comment: The first solution is more appropriate as i need to have both holiday_Desc and Holiday_code, but now instead of missing FROM, i am getting character set missmatch, on both of the solutions. Any ideas what is causing the? Country_Visited is an NVARCHAR, as is Holiday_desc and Holiday_code is a number

Comment: @TomBetts if you are getting a data type mismatch then you will need `cast` both of those fields that are numbers to a varchar2.  Not only do the number of columns have to be the same but the data types need to be the same.

Comment: CAST ( hd.Holiday_Code AS nvarchar2 )

Any idea why i am getting miss left perethesis error?

Comment: @TomBetts you have to provide the length of the `nvarchar2` -- `CAST(hd.Holiday_Code AS nvarchar2(50))`

Answer (score 2):

Well, I do see an error, but not with missing keywords. You are trying to do a `UNION` between `SELECT`s with different number of columns:

```
CREATE VIEW hd3_b 
AS 
  SELECT CASE 
           WHEN hd.country_visited = 'USA' THEN 'AMERICA' 
           WHEN hd.country_visited = 'India' THEN 'ASIA' 
           WHEN hd.country_visited = 'CHINA' THEN 'ASIA' 
           WHEN hd.country_visited = 'SPAIN' THEN 'EUROPE' 
           ELSE hd.country_visited 
         END AS hd.COUNTRY_VISITED 
  FROM   holiday_details hd 
  UNION 
  SELECT holiday_desc --holiday_code This column shouldn't be here
  FROM   holiday_details
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
CREATE VIEW hd3_b 
AS 
  SELECT CASE 
           WHEN hd.country_visited = 'USA' THEN 'AMERICA' 
           WHEN hd.country_visited = 'India' THEN 'ASIA' 
           WHEN hd.country_visited = 'CHINA' THEN 'ASIA' 
           WHEN hd.country_visited = 'SPAIN' THEN 'EUROPE' 
           ELSE hd.country_visited 
         END AS COUNTRY_VISITED 
  FROM   holiday_details hd 
  UNION 
  SELECT hd.holiday_desc, 
         hd.holiday_code 
  FROM   holiday_details hd
```

you did not need hd. in thisl line

END AS COUNTRY_VISITED

since COUNTRY_VISITED is an alias, you do not need preceed it with table alias

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you really want the UNION - it appears you're selecting from the holiday_details table in both cases.  If you'd like the country_visited to just be a column along with the related holiday_desc and holiday_code, try this:

```
CREATE VIEW hd3_b 
AS 
  SELECT CASE 
           WHEN country_visited = 'USA' THEN 'AMERICA' 
           WHEN country_visited = 'India' THEN 'ASIA' 
           WHEN country_visited = 'CHINA' THEN 'ASIA' 
           WHEN country_visited = 'SPAIN' THEN 'EUROPE' 
           ELSE country_visited 
         END AS COUNTRY_VISITED, 
  holiday_desc, 
  holiday_code 
  FROM   holiday_details
```

This syntax should work with T-SQL.  Been too long since I used Oracle to be sure if the syntax is correct there.